# Cannot connect to Heroku through cmd line

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a Django project that I have deployed on a heroku web server and use PyCharm as my IDE. I used to be able to interact with my web server with "heroku run bash", however, now when I try running "heroku run bash" I get:

```
 ▸    stat /.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory
 ▸    fork/exec /.local/share/heroku/client/bin/heroku: not a directory
```

I'm not sure what has changed, but I can't seem to connect to my heroku webserver anymore. I can still push changes using git push heroku master, but any other interaction with my heroku server doesn't seem to work anymore. I've already checked with Heroku and their systems are running just fine.

How do I reconnect to my heroku web server again with PyCharm? Or just in general?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is either due to a new version of the CLI or to an OS upgrade. 
I experienced the exact same issue on my Mac after upgrading to High Sierra and resolved it by [reinstalling the CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), this time using Homebrew.

Comment: Yep, it was the High Sierra upgrade paired with a new version of CLI. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Did the following steps, as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

1) `brew install heroku/brew/heroku`

2) `which heroku` pointed to `/usr/local/bin/heroku` so no problems there

3) finally `brew link --overwrite heroku`

After this, everything was sorted and worked as expected.